# PHP call list of Sybase database functions

Tags: php, sql, sybase

I am creating an app in PHP using a sybase database. At the moment I can call a specific database function and then use this data to create a report page using the data from my function using this code:

```
$sqld = "select WAppRCashTransactions('". $siteid ."','". $startDate ."','". $endDate ."','". $sid ."')";
  $result = sasql_query($connect, "$sqld");
    $row = sasql_fetch_row($result);
     echo $row[0];
```

however, to make this dynamic I need to call ANY function from the database that begins with

> WAppR

to produce a list of function names, so that I can then have a dynamic page that will call whichever function I select but I have no idea whatsoever how to do this!

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to find a query that will return all the functions (or procedures) that start with WAppR?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I've actually found the answer now, i'll post it!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question, here's the code if anyone needs it!

```
            <?php 

                //the SQL to get the procedure names
                $sql = "SELECT a.proc_name FROM SYSPROCEDURE a WHERE a.proc_name like 'WAppR%' ORDER BY a.proc_name";
                $funcResult = sasql_query($connect, "$sql");

                while($row = sasql_fetch_array($funcResult))
                {
                                            //function name as $functionName
                    $functionName=$row['proc_name'];
                                            //code to display the names nicely without the WAppR_
                    list($a, $title) = explode('_', $functionName);
                    $word=preg_replace('/(?<! )(?<!^)[A-Z]/',' $0', $title);

                                            //list the report names
                    echo "<li><a href='./reportManager.php?fname=$functionName'>$word</a></li>  ";
                }



            ?>
```